# How to copy label for= data to jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let me try to explain

I want to make a jQuery array with values that i have copied from a formfield.
I have the following html snippet.

```html
<p class="form">
      <input id="Dataweekend0" class="radiob" name="form[Dataweekend]" 
             value="Di. 10 aug., Za. 12 aug., Di. 16 aug." type="radio">
        <label for="Dataweekend0">Di. 10 aug., Za. 12 aug., Di. 16 aug.</label>
</p>

<p class="form">
    <input id="Dataweekend1" class="radiob" name="form[Dataweekend]" 
           value="Di. 17 aug., Za. 19 aug., Di. 23 aug." type="radio">
    <label for="Dataweekend1">Di. 17 aug., Za. 19 aug., Di. 23 aug.</label>
</p>
```

I just want to produce a jquery array from the attribute or label value. Like this:

```
[array]
[0]Di. 10 aug., Za. 12 aug., Di. 16 aug.
[1]Di. 17 aug., Za. 19 aug., Di. 23 aug.
```

I cant figure this one out myself. I think that i have to use the .each loop to extract the data.

Comment: So select the elements and map the values. http://api.jquery.com/map/ Do you know how to select the elements? Do you know how to read the value? What are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` to achieve this:

```js
var arr = $('.form input').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form">
  <input id="Dataweekend0" class="radiob" name="form[Dataweekend]" value="Di. 10 aug., Za. 12 aug., Di. 16 aug." type="radio">
  <label for="Dataweekend0">Di. 10 aug., Za. 12 aug., Di. 16 aug.</label>
</p>

<p class="form">
  <input id="Dataweekend1" class="radiob" name="form[Dataweekend]" value="Di. 17 aug., Za. 19 aug., Di. 23 aug." type="radio">
  <label for="Dataweekend1">Di. 17 aug., Za. 19 aug., Di. 23 aug.</label>
</p>
```

Comment: What if in "form" there is more to the inputs which are not interested in saving the value in the womb? This fails.

Comment: Then the selector would need to change. This will work with the sample the OP has provided.

Comment: You can also add to the map, input type and/or class? It is to learn also had not seen since that solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var array_inputs = [];
$(":input[class^=radiob]").each(function(index, element) {
    array_inputs.push(this.value);
});
```

Comment: i have tried your answer also.. unfortunately Firebug gave me this:

TypeError: this.val is not a function
 

array_inputs.push(this.val());

Comment: Sorry, you can try this.value